# Only the first rule applies in my .htacces and overrides everything else

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, server, configuration

I need to redirect some websites to another domain. My problem is only the first rule get's applied after the condition and the rest do not work.

Here is an example

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(website\.dk|website-dk|www\.website\.dk) [NC]
RewriteRule ^da/ https://www.website.se/sv/ [L,R=301]
RewriteRule ^da/test1/ https://www.website.se/sv/test1/ [L,R=301]
RewriteRule ^da/test2/foobar/ https://www.website.se/sv/test2/foobar/ [L,R=301]
RewriteRule ^da/test3/foobar123/ https://www.website.se/sv/test3/foobar123/ [L,R=301]
RewriteRule ^da/test4/ https://www.website.se/sv/test4/ [L,R=301]
```

Here the first RewriteRule works. but if i try the second one i get the same redirect as for the first one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is because pattern from `^da/` matches remaining rules also. You may try these refactored rules:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:www\.)?website[.-]dk$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^da/?$ https://www.website.se/sv/ [L,R=301,NC]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:www\.)?website[.-]dk$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^da/test1/?$ https://www.website.se/sv/test1/ [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:www\.)?website[.-]dk$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^da/test2/foobar/?$ https://www.website.se/sv/test2/foobar/ [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:www\.)?website[.-]dk$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^da/test3/foobar123/?$ https://www.website.se/sv/test3/foobar123/ [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:www\.)?website[.-]dk$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^da/test4/?$ https://www.website.se/sv/test4/ [L,R=301]
```

Note use of anchor in first rule to get precise matching and alternations in 2nd rules to cover all the cases.

Comment: This would only work if the urls are the same right ? Since it's another language this probably won't work. Sorry I'm new to this .htaccess thing

Comment: Sorry I didn't understand. It is a fix of your rules shown in answer. Are you saying your URLs are different?

Comment: Yes. For example. test2/foobar is not the same for both languages. Since they are diffenret languages.